# Draw line with matplotlib (timeseries)

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

Im plotting a big timeserie with matplotlib, the x-axis is a list of datetime.datetime objects (the way matplotlib wants its x-axis) and a list of float values, I mean, a normal timeserie.

Using plot_date(dates,values) I get this plot, I checked the values are consecutive and its fine,
[image]

Now I want to draw a line instead, using the same as above but plot_date(dates,values,fmt="-"):
[image]

What is happening? Is it a bug? Im doing something wrong?

Comment: Your data should be sorted by date, I think...

Comment: So, what is happening? Are you getting zig zags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` the `dates` and `values` into a list of tuples, sort the (date, value) pairs, unzip the pairs with `zip(*...)`, then plot:

```
dates, values = zip(*sorted(zip(dates,values)))
plot_date(dates,values, '-')
```